# How to convert an object to an array of specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
{
    "vendorName": "RAKESH KUMAR",
    "vendorContact": "8876545678",
    "vendorPAN": "ATMPB6657F",
    "vendorBankDetails": [
        {
            "vendorAccount": "3456787654",
            "vendorBankCode": "AXIS123",
            "vendorBankName": "AXIS BANK"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-09-01 00:18:10"
}
```

to

```
[0:{
    "vendorName": "RAKESH KUMAR",
    "vendorContact": "8876545678",
    "vendorPAN": "ATMPB6657F",
    "vendorBankDetails": [
        {
            "vendorAccount": "3456787654",
            "vendorBankCode": "AXIS123",
            "vendorBankName": "AXIS BANK"
        }
    ],
    "createdAt": "2021-09-01 00:18:10"
}]
```

Comment: Do you just want to put your object in an array?: `const res = [yourFirstObject];`

Comment: @NickParsons thaknyou..this works :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're just creating an array with a single element which is the aforementioned object. You can do this by surrounding the object with square brackets:

```
const myArray = [myObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myObjects = [];

myObject.push({"vendorName":"RAKESH KUMAR","vendorContact":"8876545678","vendorPAN":"ATMPB6657F","vendorBankDetails":[{"vendorAccount":"3456787654","vendorBankCode":"AXIS123","vendorBankName":"AXIS BANK"}],"createdAt":"2021-09-01 00:18:10"});

console.log(myObject);
```

[image]